# Binding to selected item in combobox using ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, reactiveui

I am trying to get the selected item from a combobox and send the value to my ViewModel. It works if I cast the binding object as a combobox and then retrieve the tag in the ViewModel, this doesn't seem to be the best approach as I also want to make this a two way binding.

Here is my combo box in the view

```
<ComboBox Name="Grade">
   <ComboBoxItem Tag="White">
       <Image Source="/Assets/Belts/White.png"/>
   </ComboBoxItem>
   <ComboBoxItem Tag="White_1">
        <Image Source="/Assets/Belts/White_1.png"/>
   </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

And here is my code behind for doing the binding using reactiveUI

```
this.Bind(this.ViewModel, 
          x => x.SelectedGrade, 
          x => (ComboBoxItem) x.Grado.SelectedItem)
          .DisposeWith(disposable);
```

This works fine, but only one way.

The question is how do I retrieve the tag of the combobox?

I have tried things along the lines of

```
this.Bind(this.ViewModel, 
          x => x.SelectedGrade, 
          x => x.Grado.SelectedItem.Tag)
          .DisposeWith(disposable);
```

and also using .ToString(), and also experimenting with selectedValue, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Btw SelectedItem will always be null in the case where you aren't using the ItemsSource approach. Doing ComboBoxItem directly in the XAML will add items into the Items collection, and only the SelectedIndex will be updated. 

Also SelectedItem isn't the ComboBoxItem, it's the item hosted by the ComboBoxItem usually provided by the MVVM approach below. You'll have to use helper methods to get access to the actual ComboBoxItem on the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ideally move away from the Tag model and towards MVVM

SelectedItem will always be null since your not using ItemSource. Using ComboBoxItem is a bad practice.  you can abstract your grade into a class then bind to the ItemSource. Then your SelectedItem property won't be null

```
public class Grade 
{
   public string ImageName { get; set; }
   public BitmapSource ImageSource => BitmapImage(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/{ImageName}")); 
}
```

In your view now do

```
this.Bind(this, vm => vm.SelectedItem, view => view.combo.SelectedItem);
this.OneWayBindBind(this, vm => vm.Grades, view => view.combo.ItemsSource);
```

Comment: OK, thanks, so I need to add all of the items using a list and then bind to the selected item?

Comment: OneWayBind to the ItemsSource property for the list, then Bind to the SelectedItem property. That will achieve what you want. Use the above MVVM style object for your binding.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have been really busy working on other parts of the program and I have only just got chance to get back to this part. I Did it how you said, and everything works fine! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to Bind `Grado.ItemSource` to the Collection that houses your data or you won't have items to select.

`this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Grades, view => view.Grado.ItemSource)`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I need it to work two-way

Comment: then change it to `this.Bind`

Comment: ItemSource binding needs to be one way or won't work. Rodney is responding to the fact your comboxitem approach won't work

Comment: ItemSource doesn't exist, and ItemsSource doesn't see any value change

Comment: I am wanting to bind to the selectedItem, and also be able to set the selected item from the viewmodel

Comment: Yes.  What we are trying to get your to understand is you have to bind two things for the Combo box to work.  You have to bind the ComboBox.ItemSource and the ComboBox.SelectedItem

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-combo-box-binding-in-mvvm-wpf/